# Add a tool bar in the gmail page

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I want to add a tool bar in the gmail page to add Functionality to gmail that i  need.

What is the best solution that you offer me ? 
Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options

1) Build a Browser Extension - such as a Chrome Extension https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

2) Use a Gmail Contextual Gadget  https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets

I would suggest you search up both for a comparison or pros/cons.